# logout from command prompt to uploading application on google app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, command-prompt

I am uploading google app engine application with the help of appcfg.py command from command prompt in windows.

But after one login I want to upload another application from the same command prompt but i cannot because this second application has no rights with the current login so i want to logout from this session on command prompt so for that what to do? It is a python application

Is there any command to logout from command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

You can run appcfg.py with `--no_cookies` to tell it not to store authentication cookies, or `-e EMAIL` to specify an email address that differs from the one in the current cookie.